# How can I fix the googe places api initMap is not a function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

We use google map places API on our site for our `input` field. Suggestion appears when the user types on the input field

Upon page load, a console error appears that says:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Vc {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Vc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…s=places%2Cgeometry&callback=initMap&ver=1:145:96"}
Promise.then (async)
Oh @ js?key=some_valid_random_key&libraries=places%2Cgeometry&callback=initMap&ver=1:145
google.maps.Load @ js?key=some_valid_random_key&libraries=places%2Cgeometry&callback=initMap&ver=1:21
(anonymous) @ js?key=some_valid_random_key&libraries=places%2Cgeometry&callback=initMap&ver=1:230
```

```js
function initMap() {
  const autocompleteInputs = document.getElementById('autoaddress');
  const options = {
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: "us"
    }
  };
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autocompleteInputs, options);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <form action="/form-action" method="GET">

    <input id="autoaddress" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Address">

    <button class="button button__primary">Show Address</button>

  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/divi/scripts/custom.js"></script>
  <!-- where initmap function exists -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=some_valid_random_key&amp;libraries=places%2Cgeometry&amp;callback=initMap&amp;ver=1"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to add `defer`  tag to the map including script.

Defer is prevent to run the script until a page is loads completely: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Do you want me to try adding `defer` script to my custom.js or to my google.maps api script?

Comment: @alexey-novikov is right add with `google.maps` api script like  `<script 
  type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=some_valid_random_key&amp;libraries=places%2Cgeometry&amp;callback=initMap&amp;ver=1"
  async defer></script>`

Comment: @alexey-novikov all right. i'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your script must load before `initMap()` function also please use `async` and `defer` in script as below.

```
<script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=some_valid_random_key&amp;libraries=places%2Cgeometry&amp;callback=initMap&amp;ver=1">
        </script>
```